# How do I make a UIImageView be half the height of the UICollectionViewCell's height in Storyboard/Interface Builder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, autolayout, uistoryboard

I'm confused as to how I'd set a `UIImageView` embedded in a `UICollectionViewCell` to half the height of this cell. When I try to create constraints between the two there doesn't appear to be a height option.

Is such a thing possible without delving into code?

Comment: Why the down vote? It'd be more helpful if you could specify why.

Comment: Question seems fine to me and doesn't deserve a downvote as `1.`IB falls under "programming" in the  OS X / iOS world; `2.`research would not give you the answer only experience with auto-layout; `3.`The question is clear and useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible. Should take about 1 minute to do.

Try the following:

1. Add a `UIView` to your `UICollectionViewCell` (you may need to make this transparent and covering the entire cell depending on your requirements)
2. Place the `UIImageView` inside the `UIView` (I recommend drag and drop in the `Document Outline`)
3. In the `Document Outline` drag from the `UIImageView` to the `UIView` and choose `Aspect Ratio`
4. Find the correct `Aspect Ratio` constraint in the `Size Inspector` and choose `Select and Edit...`
5. Make sure the `First Item` is `Image View.Height` (or alter it to be this)
6. Make sure the `Second Item` is `SuperView.Height` (or alter it to be this)
7. Change the `Multiplier` to `1:2`

Steps `5` and `6` may be the other way round in which case use `Multiplier` of `2:1`

Enjoy your `UIImageView` resized to half your `UICollectionViewCell`! You will need to set the height of your `UICollectionViewCell` elsewhere.

`Update:`I've just tested this in Xcode / IB and it works.

Comment: Ah, so you basically need an intermediary UIView? Unfortunate but makes sense, thank you. :)